# HTML/CSS In-line background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a single page, will be used as a newsletter, so my code is html/css inline.

http://jsfiddle.net/Chamberja/6t9r14ew/

I want to add a background image behind that entire table so the logo and the text will appear in the foreground.

I have tried adding

```
style="background-image: url("bg.jpg")"
```

and

```
style= "background: url(bg.jpg)"
```

So the final code looks like

```
<table style="background: url(sportip.biz/alpha.jpg)" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="deviceWidth">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:10px 20px" class="center">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://sportip.biz/nlsiplogo.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I think I am doing the in-line wrong.

Comment: try `style="background-image: url(bg.jpg)"`

Comment: maybe the `bgcolor` defined for the cells are simply covering your background image? Try to remove it

Comment: When you say 'newsletter' I assume you mean email. if that's the case you shouldn't use background images. They are not supported across all email clients

Comment: you forgot the http:// before your image

Comment: Sorted, it wasn't the http:// issue as outside of jsfiddle I copied the image url from my browser.

It seemed to be a combination of my code, which I have used cari's to fix and Fabrizio's solution seemed to get it working too.

Also, I will keep in mind what you have told me atmd. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you looking for:

```
<table style="background: url(sportip.biz/alpha.jpg)" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" class="deviceWidth">

<tr>
<td style="padding: 10px 20px" class="center">
<a href="#"><img src="http://sportip.biz/nlsiplogo.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
<!-- End Logo -->

<!-- Nav -->
<table style="position: absolute; margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="right" class="deviceWidth">

<tr>
<td class="center" style="font-size: 13px; color: #272727; font-weight: light; text-align: right; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; line-height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; padding:10px 20px; font-style:italic">
<b>Dear #name#,
Check out the latest releases of our magazines</b>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7918ypk/).

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/g0dd3vcm/1/

Find the updated JSfiddle code.

Note: Try to copy and past above url to browser facing some problem to attach link directly or on top of text

Answer (score 0):

Many email clients do not support rendering a background image inside a table. See here for some examples of workarounds: http://blog.mailermailer.com/email-design/background-images-in-html-email-the-naked-truth

Comment: While this link may provide an answer to this question, you should include further content in case the link ceases to be valid.